# Why $g(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ and $h(t) (\cos 2t, \sin 2t)$ have the same image?

Tags: calculus, parametric, parametrization

I know this might sound silly, but I don't know why $g(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ and $h(t)= (\cos 2t, \sin 2t)$ have the same image, that is the unit circle. I understand that if we eliminate the parameter on $g$, we get $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$, thus $x^2+y^2=1$ which is the equation of the unit circle, but why h has the same image if it is a different function?

Comment: Because $h(t)=g(2t).$

Comment: When you talk about paramedic equations, you treat t as a separate variable and define it for whatever you want. To cover the whole circle in g we need $2\pi$ radians but in h we only need $\pi$ radians. So if we transform t to t/2 you see that they are actually the same equation as the same change in x and y are caused relative to each other

Comment: @mfl What did you mean by that? It is false for most single values of $\;t\;$ ....or did you mean for the whole set of values of $\;t\;$ (in case in includes a whole interval of size $\;2\pi\;$?)

Comment: *paramedic equations*

Comment: @DonAntonio Since in the question there is no restriction on $t$ I have assumed $t\in \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me illustrate why on the simple functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=2x$ defined on $\mathbb R$.

These two are obviously different functions but they both have $\mathbb R$ as their image. This means that for every real number $y$ there exists a real number $x$ such that $f(x)=y$, and similarly for $g$.

Take some $y\in \mathbb R$. The function $f(x)$ will have that value when $x=y$. The function $g(x)$ will have that value when $x=y/2$. But, for any value you pick, both functions will take that value eventually, just for different values of their input variables.

Now you can apply this reasoning to your problem.

Comment: So $t$ won't affect the image? What would be the equation if I eliminate the parameter of $h$?

Comment: @davidllerenav What exactly do you mean by eliminate?

Comment: Solving the coordinate functions for t. Like $2\cos t=x$ then $\cos t =\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: @davidllerenav $t$ does affect the image in the following sense. If $t$ takes only values from $[0,\pi]$, then the image of $g(t)$ is just the upper semi-circle. Also, then $2t\in[0,2\pi]$ and $h(t)$ is the whole circle. You can see that in this case the images are different.
The fact that $g$ and $h$ have the same image *in your problem* was due to the fact that $t$ could take any real value. But if we restrict $t$ to some bounded set, then you need to carefully examine what values the two functions can take. Also note that as $t$ gets outside $[0,2\pi]$, $g$ starts repeating its values.

Comment: Oh, I see. So for example, if I have the function$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ where $g(t)=(2\cos t, \sin t)$, the function $h(t)=(2\cos \frac{t}{2}, sin \frac{t}{2})$ would have the same image? If two functions have the same image, does that mean that the equation of the image is the same, right? Even though the graph is different.

Comment: @davidllerenav But the graph **is** the image. Or, more precisely, its representation in the $xy$ plane. So two functions with the same image must have the same graph and vice versa.

Comment: But my book says: "Two different functions can have the same image [...], two different functions have different graphs".